# Chartist.js - Why is center of donut chart black?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, chartist.js

There is not a single element in that DOM I haven't tried setting color and background-color to non-black for. And #piechart_3d-1 has no styling at all.

So why does the center turn black? And how can I stop that from happening?

```
new Chartist.Pie('#piechart_3d-1', {
        series: [{ meta: 'Active|' + numAllMachines, value: numActive },
            { meta: 'Standby|' + numAllMachines, value: numStandby }]
    }, {
        donut: true,
        donutWidth: '40%',
        showLabel: false,
        width: '95%',
        height: '95%'
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I had the same problem and no one seems to have posted the solution anywhere. This is an issue with the svg fill. The black won't show up on the css inspector so it's hard to figure out. The fix is to add a fill to the path. Something like this:

```
.ct-series path {fill: white !important;}
```